# html / css restoring ul indentation for sub items in the list (should be easy)

Tags: html, css

So long story short, for ages, ive been using some CSS reset on my projects.

i was trying to make a regular sitemap page(you know with links in an unordered list) and when i do this (code below)

```
<div id="smap">
    <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="products.php">Products</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="products.php">Cantaloupes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="products.php">Watermelons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="products.php">HoneyDews</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="sales-team.php">Sales Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact / Directions</a></li>
                <li><a href="growers.phpp">Growers</a></li>
                <li><a href="packers.php">Packers</a></li>
                <li><a href="shippers.php">Shippers</a></li>
                <li><a href="importers.php">Importers</a></li>
                <li><a href="distributors.php">Distributors</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

The list comes out but the products sub-items are not indented.
In the CSS reset, the line that's doing this is

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

When i removed it,although it restored the indentation on my sitemap list, it messed up my menus throughout the site.

i want to target that lists specifically so, choosing that lists parent div which is "`smap`"
What im wondering is, by default, what is a lists vertical alignment value??

like for example, if i do this

```
#smap ul, li {vertical-alignment: SOMETHING; }
```

what is the default value for a list to be indented?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hmm, `vertical-align: baseline;` is the default value. Are you certain this is the line that's causing problems? You might try `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: i assume so because as soon as i removed it from the cssReset, it all went as it should

Comment: Is there a link to the page online somewhere? Is `margin` or `padding` set just above or below `vertical-align` declaration, that could have been affected when you removed the `vertical-align` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to revert to the default value for any property after a reset, then you should use the value `initial` - you might want to read [this article](http://nimbupani.com/safe-css-defaults.html) for more on it.

However, the `ul` indentation is given by the `padding-left` of the `ul` - see http://dabblet.com/gist/3144582. I think [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align) shouldn't influence that.

Comment: `initial` is helpful only in modern browsers; it wasn't introduced until CSS3. Which means if IE6,7,8 are of concern, you cannot use it.

Comment: Thanks @ SET SAIL....that didnt work BUT, i display block and padding-left it and it worked....thanks lol.

Comment: Good work, all! +1 to Ana for getting you on the right track with padding :}

Comment: @SetSailMedia Yup, that's true about the `initial` value.